# Ckeditor appendTo does not recognize config

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to use the ckeditor appendTo method with the config options specified in the javascript:

```
var config = {tabSpaces: 4};
editor1 = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'chaptertextareadiv', config, text );
```

This successfully adds to the page, but the config option is not functioning -- I mean, the tab key behavior is not modified.

The documentation shows that passing a configuration option is valid, but gives no examples. All the examples show null in that spot.

I'm using the basic editor:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.3/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Is it actually possible to specify config options this way? Or is there something more that I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The tab key is not included with the basic or standard editor. You can either use the full editor which includes it, or download the tab plugin separately and configure it.
This is working for me now:

```
var config = {extraPlugins: 'tab',
              tabSpaces: 4,
              allowedContent: true, 
              height: '30em',
              removeButtons: 'Strike,Subscript,Superscript'};
editor1 = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'chaptertextareadiv', config, html );
```